# jtextPane.setText("") is keeping the format from whatever was previously in it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextpane, settext

I am redirecting `System.out` and `System.err` in a `textPane` enclosed in a `scrollPane` to show a log of what is happening to the user.

I have also implemented a simple button that when pressed it sets the `textPane` text to "" in order to clear it.

What I have found now is that `.setText("")` actually keeps the formatting of whatever was shown earlier and also it keeps the line breakers. For example I have the `System.err` being shown in red and if in my clear button I replace `.setText("")` with .setText("test") and then if I have red text in the `textPane` then the text will be replaced by *test* but the word test will be red!

Now what my problem is, is that if I press the clear button even once, every time a new message comes to the `textPane` it will have an unnecessary permanent blank line at the start. So here are my questions:

1. Why is this even happening, how can it somehow preserve the format from before?
2. How do I fix this?

**Pressing a button that will use `System.out`**

[image: 1]

**Pressing the clear button**

[image: 2]

**Pressing the button at step 1 again**

[image: 3]

**Clearing and pressing a button that will use `System.err`**

[image: 4]

**Clearing and pressing the same button that will use `System.err`**

[image: 5]

So as you can see if I use `System.out` and then `.setText("")` then `System.out` gets bugged. if I use `System.err` and then `.setText("")` then `System.err` gets bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using the [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) class to do your logging.

It indeed has a bug that will add the EOF string to the Document when the text from the Document has been cleared.

Anyway, I just fixed the bug and you can download the new version.

Comment: That is indeed the class I am using (just a little bit modified). It works like a charm now thank you very much.

Comment: `That is indeed the class I am using` - don't you think that is important information for the question? People don't know you are using a 3rd party class and will think the problem is with the JTextPane.

Comment: I double checked the class first and thought that the problem did not lie there so I didn't want to post a wall of code for people to traverse through if it was not needed (as I was assuming at the time) unless I was specifically asked to. I wanted to post whatever I thought was relevant to the problem (which in the end I was mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

- For the text color, when you call System.err, you change the color of the text to red. The best thing to reset the color is: In the constructor, save the original Color of the text area like this: `Color originalColor = inputText.getForeground();` and when you want to reset the text, do this:

  `inputText.setForeground(originalColor); 
   inputText.setText("");`
- Concerning the empty line at the beginning, basically it should not put this line, but maybe it's happening because you are using System.out. Can you try to display the text using setText() rather than System.out.